# ASP.Net Core application and Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was debugging ASP.Net Core application and noticed strange thing about Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() output. Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() call gives me dictionary with 75 entries in it while environment variables configured at My Computer-> Properties->Environment variables shows very less entries i.e. around 20 entries. Please check screenshot below which shows both output from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() and environment variables from my computer -> properties.
[image]
So my question is from where Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() is getting those additional entries. I am specifically interested in knowing source of entries which starts with "ASPNETCORE". Is it stored somewhere else. I am sure that these additional entries are not stored in my application's configuration file(s).

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables not on your user or the machine are *on the process*.

Visual Studio sets some of them when you launch the application. You should be able to modify them in the project's Properties.

Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer and click **Properties**.

Open the **Debug** tab, and here you can add/edit/remove environment variables.

[image: Environment variables in VS project properties]

These environment variables are stored in Properties/launchSettings.json.

However, this answer does not completely answer the question, there are some environment variables coming from somewhere else as well. They might be set by ASP.NET Core itself / IIS module / IIS Express.

Comment: See also: `System.EnvironmentVariableTarget` referred to here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40df59yb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Juunas. I had already checked it however there is only one entry as shown in your screenshot but there are almost 50 more entries which Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() returns for which I couldn't find source.

Comment: Very true. I honestly am not sure where those come from, could be ASP.NET Core, could be IIS Express.

Comment: @ta.speot.is : Checked link you provided and looks like EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process may be source of additional entries though not sure about it.